# How to remove duplicates from list?

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

So i have an interface.

```
public interface ARecord {
    public BigInteger getAutoID();
    public String getACompId();
}
```

and

```
public class APPPRecord extends AbstratAPRecord implements ARecord{
    private BigInteger autoID;
    private String ACompId = null;

    //setter and getter
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.getACompId().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        APPPRecord e = null;
        if(obj instanceof APPPRecord){
            e = (APPPRecord) obj;
        }
        if(this.getACompId().equals(e.getACompId())){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        } 
    }
}
```

In service,

```
    List<APPPRecord> PFRecord = null;
    while(scroll.next()) {
      APPPRecord item = (APPPRecord) scroll.get(0);
      List<ARecord> recs = new ArrayList<ARecord>();
      recs.addAll(PFRecord);
```

My PFRecord list has results that are being duplicated. I have to use hash maps that can check for ACompId contains key. If the key already exists don't pass it to recs.addAll. How can I go about doing this? Any help appreciated

I tried Set and still see duplicate results with HashCode() and equals() implementation in my model class.

```
    for (ARecord records:recs){
        uniqueRecs.put(records.getACompId(), records);
        Set<String> keys = uniqueRecs.keySet();
        for(String key: keys){
            log.debug("keys " + key);
        }
    }
```

Also tried hashMaps.

```
    HashMap<String, ARecord > uniqueRecs = new HashMap<String, ARecord >();
    for(ARecord records:recs){
       if(!uniqueRecs.containsKey(records.getACompId())){
            uniqueRecs.put(records.getACompId(), records);
            for (String key : uniqueRecs.keySet()) {
                log.debug("unique record " + key);
            }
        }                       
    }
```

Both of them still produce duplicate results. Any ideas? I'm running out of ideas to ignore the duplicates.

Comment: The way to remove duplicates from a `List` is `list = new ArrayList<>(new LinkedHashSet<>(list));`. It will only work if `equals` and `hashCode` are properly implemented. Can we see your code for these methods?

Comment: I've just seen your mistake. In `equals` you're comparing `getACompId()` whereas in `hashCode` you're using `getAssetId()`. That won't work.

Comment: sorry about the confusion. I mistyped it or something. It actually is getACompId in my code that's not working. I fixed it above as well.

Comment: In that case, I'm stuck. I suggest you try to provide a complete example we can all run, because at the moment your snippets don't seem to relate to one another.

Comment: Move the loop where you print out the keys (`for (String key : uniqueRecs.keySet())`) outside of the other `for` loop and you'll see that there are actually no duplicate keys in the map.

Comment: silly me. that was the issue. Nested loops.